# Password as a function and ontime not working correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I will try to be as explicit as I can with my problem.

I have a workbook which has all the sheets protected by password and on it lots of codes run when forms are run.

Now this workbook is run on 3 different departments, and in each has a department head who has his own password. The easiest way I tried doing this was first, setting in a module:

```
Public pass As String
```

I also have the workbook on a start event to define this variable:

```
pass = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pass").Range("A1").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pass").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

So as you can see I store the password in a A1 of sheet "Pass"

This way the department heads can change there password whenever they want by a form I created. This makes their password secret.

Now all of the workbook goes fine except when it goes into the superuser mode that I created that shows the department heads some hidden sheets and allows them to do monthly audit.

They access this super user mode through a form which has this code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
   Dim min As Long 
   Dim sVal As String
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim wb As Worksheet
   Dim ktime As Date
   Dim wn As Worksheet
   Dim wc As Worksheet
   Set ws = Worksheets("Formularios")
   Set wb = Worksheets("LookupList")
   Set wn = Worksheets("Coordenador")
   Set wc = Worksheets("Time")



If Trim(Me.txtPass.Value) = "" Then
 Me.txtPass.SetFocus
 MsgBox "Por favor inserir Password"
 Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.txtMinuto.Value) = "" Then
  Me.txtMinuto.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Por favor inserir Tempo"
  Exit Sub
 End If

min = CInt(txtMinuto)
sVal = txtPass.Value

If sVal = pass Then
  For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Worksheet.Unprotect Password:=sVal
    Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  Next

  ktime = Now + TimeSerial(0, min, 0)
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pass").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coordenador").Range("O" & Range("Coordenador!O1048000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = ktime
  Application.OnTime ktime, "CloseC"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coordenador").Range("P11") = ktime
  ws.Protect Password:=pass
  wb.Protect Password:=pass
  wn.Protect Password:=pass
  wb.Visible = xlSheetHidden
  Calc
  wc.Unprotect Password:=pass
  wc.Range("I1").Value = "c"
  wc.Protect Password:=pass
  Audit
  Unload Me
  Else: MsgBox "There is a problem - check your password, capslock, etc."
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see the form asks how many minutes for them to be Super user. And it runs "CloseC" macro at the end of the time, which is the macro that puts everything back together with the passwords and ends Super user.

Here is my issue: If a department Head runs that form twice or more times, in theory it should just add the new time to "Ontime" feature of excel running the macro "CloseC" on the last time that he introduced, however this is not happening and excel is creating a new "Ontime" instance, and still running CloseC on the first time. 
When this happens, something strange happens with the code that it no longer lets you run the Super user form, instead it gives the error that the password is incorrect. I can overpass this last error by closing and opening the workbook.

I appreciate any help or ways to improve my code.

Comment: Your theory is incorrect. `OnTime` will always simply add a new scheduled run - you have to explicitly cancel any previous scheduled one.

Comment: Reading material for you:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel  and  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

Comment: Why even put a time limit on the user anyway? There has to be better design than that, no?

Comment: @Rory Just to see if I understood you correctly, for every time that someone runs the form I would have to cancel the older ontime schedule already been set?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman This is just a precaution so the Department heads don't leave super user open. It's a fail safe that helps keep the program from being tempered with.

Comment: @PedroTeixeiradeFreitas - Use the  `Workbook_Open` event to always user super user mode is turned off so everytime someone opens it there is no danger of them seeing SuperUser mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Rory comment I got this added to the code:

```
If wn.Range("O2") <> "" Then
        For Tsweep = 2 To Range("Coordenador!O1048000").End(xlUp).Row
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Range("Coordenador!O" & Tsweep).Value, Procedure:="CloseC", Schedule:=False
        Next Tsweep
        wn.Range("O:O").ClearContents
    End If
```

It appears to be working. 
Thank you for your help.